# Compilation error - no matching function for call to 'Exception::Exception(Exception)'

Tags: c++

I can not solve this problem for a while. I would be glad for some advice.

When I try to throw an exception (self created one in Java style)

```
throw Exception ();
```

compiler make a protest:

> DataTypes/Date.cpp:24: error: no matching function for call to `Exception::Exception(Exception)'
>   DataTypes/Date.cpp:24: error:   in thrown expression

It does not work with any of the constructors I have. What is the problem?
Here is header file of the Exception:

```
class Exception
{

public:
 Exception(void);
    explicit Exception(const char *);
    explicit Exception(const Exception &);
    Exception(const char *, const Exception &);
 virtual ~Exception();

 const char * message;
 const Exception & cause;

};
```

I should mention that when I leave just implicit constructor and the second one it works.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Also (as a comment, since this isn't your question), in C++ you really should derive your exceptions from `std::exception`, or better yet one of its more specific sub-classes. This allows a last-resort exception handler that catches `std::exception` to at least do something marginally useful with it (such as print the contained error message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your copy constructor is marked explicit, which means it isn't really a copy constructor. Thrown objects must be copyable.

To elaborate:

The `explicit` keyword means that a single-argument constructor cannot be used to implicitly convert a variable of the argument type to an object of the constructed type. You have to do it explicitly with the class name. For example, your constructor from `const char*` is explicit, so the compiler will never implicitly convert a `const char*` to a new object of type `Exception`, without you writing out `Exception("some string here")`. On the other hand, you do want the compiler to be able to implicitly make one `Exception` object into another `Exception` object (that's what a copy constructor does!), so by taking the constructor that would otherwise be the copy constructor and marking it with the `explicit` keyword, you have completely eliminated its ability to make copies.

Comment: Well, it really is a copy ctor, even though it must be invoked explicitly. It's just not a very useful copy ctor. `:)` +1 Nevertheless.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I can see it now. Originally it was not thought as a copy constructor. I wanted it for polymorphic structure of exceptions (like in Java). I have to do it differently.

Answer (score 2):

By `throw Exception();` you create a local instance of the exception class, which is then copied off the stack. Remove `explicit` from the copy-constructor.

#### Edit:

If your copy constructor doesn't do anything - just omit it. The compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: I see. I have not noticed that it is actually copy constructor. It was thought as an constructor with reference to exception which caused throw of this exception (like Java). Thanks.

Comment: No, C++ exceptions are different from Java ones. No easy stack traces here.

Comment: The parens are required in C++.

Comment: Oops, you are right, was thinking about new for some reason. Correcting.